# Redirect 301 Apache PHP File

Tags: php, apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect this:

```
www.site1.com/downs/pafiledb.php?action=download&id=NUMBER-OF-DOWNLOAD
```

to

```
www.site2.com/downloads/NUMBER-OF-DOWNLOAD
```

Example, I entry in:

```
www.site1.com/downs/pafiledb.php?action=download&id=795
```

and go to this address by 301 redirect:

```
www.site2.com/downloads/795
```

I use server Apache and want do this by PHP file or a RewriteRule, but I've tried several ways and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was, but those two lines added to the end of pafiledb.php should do the trick:

```
header('Location: http://site2.com/downloads/'.$_GET['id'], true, 301);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
if( isset( $_GET[id] )
   {
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header( "location:www.site2.com/downloads/" . $_GET[id]);
    }
```